# How to use Tall Goat and other rewards?

Tags: goat-simulator

When I get the trophy rewards, like tall goat, how do I actually activate it and become tall? Thanks.

Comment: You need to go back to the main menu and add it as a 'modifier' or something, I forget the exact labels.  I'll let somebody else answer in more detail.

Comment: Found it! I had to start a 'custom game', then select modifiers from there. Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

It depends what platform you're on. In mobile, you click the goat symbol in-game on the top left. From there, scroll, and you will see your goats. For others... well, I don't know. But here's a funny use for Tall Goat:
Lick people and toss them in the river. It's very easy because Tall Goat is a giraffe and the body is so high off the ground, giving you a lot of control.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go back to the main menu and start a **Custom Game**.

From there you can add **Modifiers**, which change stuff in the game.  As you unlock new goats, you can add them as **Modifiers** to change your goat appearance.  This is how you activate most of the unlockable stuff.

To change your **Modifiers**, you will have to go back to the menu and start a new **Custom Game**.